# dygraph: updateOptions with persistence

Tags: dygraphs

I am changing the datafile with updateOptions, but it there a chance to keep the old dataset with a lower opacity. For example consider this sequence:

1. `ges.updateOptions({'file': file1})`
2. The user change something and the file is now file2
3. I update with `ges.updateOptions({'file': file2})`, but is there a way to keep file1 with lower opacity, so that I can compare file1 and file2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dygraphs is a tool for charting data. It makes almost no effort to manage the data for you.

If you want to do this sort of data manipulation, you'll be better off issuing the XMLHttpRequests yourself and converting them to [native format](http://dygraphs.com/data.html#array). This gives you maximum flexibility in controlling your data.